# Ratio test: $n^\sqrt{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to determine the radius of convergence of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n n^\sqrt{n}$$

I have, by use of the ratio test, written: (Because I know it tends to 1)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)^\sqrt{n+1}}\to 1$$

But I am unable to demonstrate why this is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The root test is easier here, by the way.

Comment: Write the quotient as $$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\cdot (n+1)^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}.$$ It should not be impossible to show that both factors converge to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\dfrac{n^{\sqrt n}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}=\exp[\sqrt n\log n-\sqrt{n+1}\log (n+1)].
$$
And
$$
\sqrt n\log n-\sqrt{n+1}\log (n+1)=\sqrt n\log n-\sqrt{n+1}\log n + \sqrt{n+1}\log n-\sqrt{n+1}\log (n+1)\\
=(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1})\log n + \sqrt{n+1}(\log n-\log (n+1))\\
=\frac{\log n}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}-\sqrt{n+1}\,\log\left( 1+\frac1n\right).
$$
The first term clearly goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. For the second, 
$$
0\leq\sqrt{n+1}\,\log\left( 1+\frac1n\right)\leq\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n\to0.
$$
Going back to our first expression,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{\sqrt n}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}=\exp[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\log n-\sqrt{n+1}\log (n+1)]\to e^0=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the root test instead?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^{\sqrt n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{\sqrt n}n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac1{\sqrt n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}} = e^0 = 1$$

Comment: The OP is not asking for the solution. Instead, the OP is asking for why the limit written down is true.

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar and how do you know that? are you the OP?

Comment: No, but that is explicitly what the OP states.

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar ever heard of the XY problem? go google that

Comment: $$n^{\frac{\sqrt n}n}  \neq (n^2)^\frac{n}{n^2}$$

Comment: @user2345215 Excepting that when you replace $n$ by $n^2$, you go to a subsequence. And the fact that the subsequence converges to 1 doesnot prove that the sequence is convergent.... So, while the two limits are equivalent, your proof doesn't prove it...

Comment: @user2345215 And I would recommend you try not to be so aggressive with your comments... Or if you must be, make sure first that you are right before making such comments...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Using the root test, we evently need to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{^{1/\sqrt{n}}}$. Set 
$f(x)=lnx/\sqrt{x}$, for $x\geq 1$. Then when $x\rightarrow \infty $, $f(x)\rightarrow 0 $.
So $e^{f(x)}=x^{1/\sqrt{x}}\rightarrow 1$ since $f$ is continuous. That means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n^{^{1/\sqrt{n}}}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question. Consider:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)^\sqrt{n+1}}$$
I would suggest we put $t = n+1$ and substitute it into the expression above, remember that as $x \to \infty$ we have that $t \to \infty$. So our new expression becomes: $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac {(t-1)^{\sqrt {t-1}}} {t^{\sqrt t}}$$ Now observe: $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac {(t-1)^{\sqrt {t-1}}} {t^{\sqrt t}} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \left({\frac {(t-1)^{\frac {\sqrt {t-1}} {\sqrt t}}} t}\right)^{\sqrt t}$$

Now try to use some elementary algebra and simplify the numerator, then use the standard limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {n}^{\sqrt n} = 1$$

I hope this helped, if you detect any mistakes in my comment please tell me. If you need further help, write a comment.